# Trouble mixing UISegmentedControl with Core Data

Tags: ios, database, core-data, uisegmentedcontrol

I have been searching for the answer for a couple of weaks now but I just can't seem to find it. I have been trying to get a UISegmentedControl's data to save in the Core Data but I can't do it, it keeps showing me an errors and warnings, hope you can help me.

I have something like this:

```
#import "DetailScoutingViewController.h"

@interface DetailScoutingViewController ()

    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *name;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *number;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *considered;

    - (IBAction)save:(id)sender;
    - (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;

    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObject *teamData;

@end

@implementation DetailScoutingViewController
@synthesize teamData;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (self.teamData) {

        [self.name setText:[self.teamData valueForKey:@"name"]];
        [self.number setText:[self.teamData valueForKey:@"number"]];
        [self.considered setSelectedSegmentIndex:[self.teamData valueForKey:@"considered"]];
    }
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if (self.teamData) {
        // Update existing device
        [self.teamData setValue:self.name.text forKey:@"name"];
        [self.teamData setValue:self.number.text forKey:@"number"];
        [self.teamData setValue:self.considered.selectedSegmentIndex forKey:@"considered"];

    } else {
        // Create a new device
        NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Teams" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [newDevice setValue:self.name.text forKey:@"name"];
        [newDevice setValue:self.number.text forKey:@"number"];
    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The UITextField's data saves without a problem, the only problem I have is the UISegmentedControl. What should I do?

Comment: Perhaps viewDidLoad is too early in the life cycle?

Comment: try [[self.teamData valueForKey:@"considered"] integerValue]

Comment: @VictorEngel I'm pretty sure it's not that because, as I said earlier, the text fields save perfectly, the problem comes when I'm trying to save the segmented control

Comment: Are you trying to save TO core data or update the segmented control FROM core data. Your description indicates one, but your code indicates the other. I agree with @Dan Shelly's suggestion. Otherwise types don't match.

Comment: @VictorEngel I'm trying to do both. I already edited the code below.

Comment: What are the errors and warnings you mention?

Comment: @Wain It says `Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'NSInteger' (aka int) to parameter of type 'id'` in this line of code: `[self.teamData setValue:self.considered.selectedSegmentIndex forKey:@"considered"];`

Comment: So you should really fix that. I have covered it in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [self.teamData valueForKey:@"considered"]

This returns what is likely to be an `NSNumber` instance, but `setSelectedSegmentIndex:` expects an NSInteger so you should be using:

```
[self.considered setSelectedSegmentIndex:[[self.teamData valueForKey:@"considered"] integerValue]];
```

You also need to change the corresponding save code to:

```
[self.teamData setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:self.considered.selectedSegmentIndex] forKey:@"considered"];
```

This bit of code is not helping:

```
if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
    context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
}
```

change to:

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
    context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
}
```

At some point in some other controller you should be setting `...teamData = ...`. If you aren't, then your controller will always be creating a new `Teams` managed object and inserting it into the data store. In this case, you don't set the `self.considered.selectedSegmentIndex` so you will never store it. It's only ever stored when you already have a `Teams` object.

Comment: THANKS A LOT MAN! IT TOTALY WORKED!